# Why does the classList.toggle function not work with Jinja?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not sure why I'm getting this bug. All the class document variables should be correct, the CSS shouldn't have any issues, and JavaScript is linked properly and gets executed when needed to.

Regardless of that, everything works perfectly fine except the `classList.toggle` function. For some reason it just does not toggle. I tried console logging the actual variable to see if it returns a undefined, but it returns the actual div.

If someone could help guide me to the right direction on fixing this issue, that would be great! Thank you!

**JavaScript file**

```
window.onload = function() {

    console.log("hambruger.js has successfully loaded.")

    var hamburgerMenuIcon = document.querySelector('.hamburger-menu-icon')
    var hamburgerMenu = document.querySelector('.hamburger-navbar')
    var closeButton = document.querySelector('.close-btn')

    hamburgerMenuIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log("Added class")
        hamburgerMenu.classList.toggle("change")
    })

}
```

**CSS File**

```
.change {
    left: 0px;
}

.hamburger-navbar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    left: -250px;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

**HTML File**

```
      <div class="main-header sticky">
        <div class="header-content">
          <div class="site-title">
            <img class="hamburger-menu-icon" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/20/000000/menu--v1.png"/>
            <h3 class="title-text">TITLE</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="site-buttons">
            <button class="upload-btn">Upload</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="hamburger-navbar">
        <div class="navbar-buttons">
           <div class="login-button">
             <button class="login-btn">Login</button>
           </div>
           <div class="signup-button">
            <button class="signup-btn">Sign Up</button>
          </div>
           <div class="close-hamburger-menu">
             <p class="close-btn">Close  Menu</p>
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

**Console Output**
[image: console]

As you can see in the image, the JavaScript file is connected, and is working perfectly fine. It just does *not* toggle for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine.
Status message print added to show it working.

https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSeagoe/m30qd9tj/6/

html

```
<p id='status'></p>
```

js

```
hamburgerMenu.classList.toggle("change");
msg = document.querySelector('#status'); // added
msg.innerText = hamburgerMenu.classList.toString(); // added
```

[image: ClickToToggle]